# Programmatically create calendar event in outlook.com like .ics

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, outlook.com

I'm trying to understand if it's possible to use a url or api to open an Outlook.com calendar event in the users outlook.com/calendar with prefilled information?  Essentially, just like an .ics file but using the webview in outlook.com

**Story**: as a user with no experience with outlook calendars, I want to click a button on a website and have it open a new calendar event (values pre-filled) in my outlook.com, so I spend as little setting up a meeting.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the [create event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/calendar-post-events?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) operation in the Microsoft Graph and then retrieve the weblink property of the event you just created to redirect the user to it.

Comment: Thanks for the link. very helpful in pointing me in the right direction. So the logic would be something like: Custom UI creates request body, sends to POST /users/{id | userPrincipalName}/calendar/events, wait for success and returned json {}, redirect user to weblink or whatever.  BTW, congrats on the new position at MS!

Comment: @baywet is there a way in outlook to send metadata in the email that can be converted to a calendar event like the Google metadata?

Comment: Do you know how to get the userid and the calendarid?

Answer (score 0):

I developed a free web app to produce ics and host it on AWS. its free to use.
I will appreciate to get your feedback.
https://calex.link